# upload non seekable streams in minio using dotnet client

Tags: minio

I create streams on the fly and I want to upload then to a minio storage. 
However PutObjectAsync expects the length of the stream, which is unknown, as the stream is non seekable. 
Is there any workaround about this ?
Of course I could read my stream fully into a memorystream and use that instead, but beacause of the size of the streams (several gigaBs) that is not an option.